Did the Rings also slow down the fading of the Elves?
I think the following sums up the motive for the creation of the Rings of Power.

They wanted the peace and bliss and perfect memory of ‘The West’, and yet to remain on the ordinary earth where their prestige as the highest people, above wild Elves, dwarves, and Men, was greater than at the bottom of the hierarchy of Valinor
...
They became sad, and their art (shall we say) antiquarian, and their efforts all really a kind of embalming - even though they also retained the old motive of their kind, the adornment of earth, and the healing of its hurts
...
The chief power (of all the rings alike) was the prevention or slowing of decay. -- Letter #131

But we are also told that the Elves themselves also grew (old) quicker in Middle-earth; did the Rings work the same way on the Elves as they worked on Gollum, etc.? Was it part of the reasons the Elves made the Rings? (Just wondering whether Amazon's show gets at least something from canon).

If the Three had any impact on their bearers then it isn't that obvious compared to their fellow Elves. We aren't told that eg Celeborn looks older than Galadriel, instance. The "Elves grow older quicker in Middle-earth" was a really early idea that wasn't specific to Elves, but rather time itself "passed quicker" after the Sun first rose, and similarly growth/change. In the later version where Tolkien was carefully working out aging rates calibrated the Legendarium events, I don't recall he mentioned this whole "aging faster in M-e" idea.

If you are wondering whether the Three (and possible the other 16) had an umbrella effect on 'all the Elves' that is separate from general 'slowing of decay'/preservation, I'm not sure that's really given in the text. I personally take the accelerated fading of the Elves in M-e in Rings of Power as a shorthand for the general audience of a much more complex and metaphysically sophisticated situation that Tolkien developed. (The show gets a lot from Tolkien's texts, aside from changes due to adaptation, but that's a separate discussion)

@DavidRoberts I think these are fairly late notes indicating different aging rates between Aman and Middle-earth: '144 SY in Aman = 1 year of Elf-life, but 100 SY in Beleriand = 1 year'; 'in Aman where “waning” was retarded'; 'The Quendian rate originally corresponded to the Valian and it so remained in Aman. But by each act or choice which as it were allied the Quendi, or any group of them, more closely with “Arda Marred”, the rate of “growth” became quicker (for the tendency towards physical decay was increased).'

Thanks for digging those out! I think 'each act or choice which ...allied [Elves] more closely with "Arda Marred"' is a little vague, to say the least. Going to M-e is probably intended to be one of these acts/choices, but presumably a big part of this were things like doing some kinslayings. And using items whose very makeup was influenced by a friendly lord of gifts, where does that sit? And the whole discussion about how it would have been best for the Valar to leave the Eldar in M-e in the first place? Where does that sit? (usual caveats about inconsistencies in Tolkien, of course!)

Eugene, can you give an exact citation the passage(s)?

@DavidRoberts Sure! Respectively in ch. IX, X, and XII, or p64, p71, and p88 in the Nature of Middle-earth.

Thanks for that!

Galadriel said in the Mirror of Galadriel:

‘I pass the test,’ she said. ‘I will diminish, and go into the West, and remain Galadriel.’

It is the unpowering of her ring that will lead to her diminishment.   The other choice, taking the One Ring, would allow her to grow by absorbing a large part of Sauron's power.
So it seems that not only did her ring slow her fading, but taking a more powerful ring would reverse her fading, for a while.

She will diminish by leaving Middle-earth where she has "the prestige as the highest people, above wild Elves, dwarves, and Men", instead she will be "at the bottom of the hierarchy of Valinor", well, not exactly the bottom, but she's probably not having an independent realm to rule in Valinor.

The main reason she left Valinor was that "she yearned to see the wide unguarded lands and to rule there a realm at her own will". But when offered "the Ring of Power and the dominion of Middle-earth of which she had dreamed ... and she rejected it, and passing the last test departed from Middle-earth for ever".

So I think by "diminish" she means she's giving up her power and prestige. I don't think it's about "fading".

Thanks for your comments.  Galadriel said "I will diminish, and go into the West", not the other way around.  I suppose she would have chosen to stay in Middle Earth undiminished if her ring had continued working, but that option was not on the table.
